# Create Network Share with permissions

Tags: c#, .net, network-shares

I didn't find any good info or library on the inet, about how to create a network share and set permission for a local group. I'm using c# and Windows Server 2008.

Does anyone have some good resources or sample to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pinvoke or WMI,

there is a very nice article on this on Code Project: [How to create a file share using .NET framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/pinvokeaddshare.aspx)

the key of the whole thing is the following Windows API:

```
[DllImport("Netapi32.dll")]
public static extern int NetShareAdd([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
string strServer, Int32 dwLevel, IntPtr buf, IntPtr parm_err);
```

for using WMI, MSDN "knows": [Create method of the Win32_Share Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)