# Sync folders on all Azure Cloud Instances

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

Just deployed my App to Azure. Everything works fine.

I'm currently running some legacy code on my app that I cannot upgrade right now, and it makes use of some files on the local VM Storage.

I need to find a way to keep all the cloud instances folder synced. Someone wrote a plugin that seems to do this using the Microsoft Sync Framework, but it runs on Azure SDK 1.5:
https://github.com/Interop-Bridges/Windows-Azure-File-System-Durability-Plugin

Does anyone know of a similar implementation for the current version of the SDK? or a better solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [CloudDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WINDOWSAZURE.STORAGECLIENT.CLOUDDRIVE%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) feature of Windows Azure. You can put a .VHD file into the blob storage and mount it as a drive in your compute service.

But keep in mind that if you have multiple instance in your computing service, only one instance has read/write access to the VHD. You should share the VHD Drive among all your instances using standard network share technology.

Comment: Yes, but this will solve syncing for only one of the instances. I want to keep them all synced

Comment: If you use a network share that allows all instances to have R/W access to the VHD you can keep all of them in sync.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this upon each web role startup?

Comment: You might try this in the OnStart method of your Service EntryPoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470214/create-network-share-with-permissions

Comment: Thank @Nico. Got this running but it's not very efficient (and it drives up costs). I ended up moving everything to websites